# Xamarin.Forms, On Android, there is a black bar across the top of the screen

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having a strange problem on Android, when i run on Android emulator I have the below black bar running across the screen, it does the same on my physical device Samsung S8.

[image]

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="za.co.cofairsoft.cof">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:label="COF@" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
</application>
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:COFATV2" 
x:Class="COFATV2.COFATV2Page">
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
<local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:UserInfo />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
</style>
<!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#bf1f27</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#BC0009</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#bf1f27</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#bf1f27</item>
</style>
<style name="splashscreen" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_centered</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Below is my Main Activity

```
[Activity(Label = "COFATV2.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/splashscreen", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Below is also code in Tabbar and Toolbar under Layout:

Tabbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: please share xml of your layout

Comment: Without your XAML code we can't even begin to find out why that is :)

Comment: We need to see your xaml/cs pageto help. Seems like a negative top margin.

Comment: I have edited my post, sorry about that.

Comment: I once had a similar problem (but the bar at the top of the screen was white). It was because my MasterDetail page was not on the root of my stack - not the first page of my application, because the user first had to log in before accessing the MasterDetail page. So I made the navigation stack empty before showing the MasterDetail page and the white bar suddenly disappeared, the problem was solved. So do you navigate to your MasterDetail page from another page ?

Comment: Hi Anto, I do, I also have a login page. How would make the stack empty.

Comment: I was just thinking, my app has login page only if the user isn't authenticated, if the user is authenticated it goes straight to same page and i still experience the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I have found the culprit, i am in my MainAvtivity calling

```
Theme = "@style/splashscreen"
```

in my style code

```
<style name="splashscreen" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_centered</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

the splashscreen code:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/COFATSPLASH"
android:gravity="center"
android:color="@android:color/white"/>
```

gravity="center" is the problem, without it it works the problem however is that my image in the splashscreen is to big and warpped.

not sure if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Hi I just wanted to further add that I resolve the issue that was caused by the splash screen, I used a **layer-list** with a white background and the image in the layerlist list.